# How to deserialize an enum variant containing a vector of structs?

Tags: rust, serde

I am still fairly new to using Rust and lifetimes still mystify me. I am trying to get something like this simplified bit of code working:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    str_field: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum MyEnum<'a> {
    // This compiles
    #[serde(borrow)]
    MyStructField(MyStruct<'a>),
    
    // This does not compile
    #[serde(borrow)]
    MyStructVecField(Vec<&'a MyStruct<'a>>),
}


fn main() {
    println!("Hello World");
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&'a MyStruct<'a>: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:16:22
     |
16   |     MyStructVecField(Vec<&'a MyStruct<'a>>),
     |                      ^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `&'a MyStruct<'a>`
     |
     = help: the following implementations were found:
               <MyStruct<'a> as Deserialize<'de>>
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Deserialize<'_>` for `Vec<&'a MyStruct<'a>>`
note: required by a bound in `newtype_variant`
    --> /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/serde-1.0.136/src/de/mod.rs:2118:12
     |
2118 |         T: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `newtype_variant`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I did find the serde deserializer lifetimes documentation, but I did not firmly grasp it, at least not well enough to solve my problem. I am not quite sure what I have to do to get it to work. Can I make it work using derive? Will I have to write a custom Deserialize impl? Can it work at all? Bonus points if you explain the problem.

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=72146b53aab992e4f7fa5b9e8cd9a59d)

Comment: You don't need the `&'a`, see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5a2d091e550a8e24edd7c26452364a9). Someone else can probably explain the reason better than me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize a reference. However by nature a reference points to data stored elsewhere. This works fine for `&str` or `&[u8]` since they are just fat-pointers to raw bytes and can just reference the data they are being deserialized from. However, this also means that the outputted type will depend on the lifetime of the input data. Generally this is great since we can perform zero-copy deserialization. The `#[serde(borrow)]` acts as a bit of boilerplate so it can get the lifetimes requirements correct when implementing the trait.

However, `MyStruct<'a>` is different. It does not exist in the input data so it must be created during deserialization. This causes issues if we want to deserialize a reference to it. `MyStruct<'a>` does not exist in the input and a value on the stack does not live for long enough either.

Luckily this has an easy fix. Just use an owned value. This still counts as zero-copy deserialization since there was nothing to copy in the first place.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum MyEnum<'a> {
    #[serde(borrow)]
    MyStructField(MyStruct<'a>),
    #[serde(borrow)]
    MyStructVecField(Vec<MyStruct<'a>>),
}
```

The `Vec` isn't relevant to the issue. `MyStructField(&'a MyStruct<'a>)` is just as invalid and would have produced the same error.